# How to do a division without using recursion or the `/` operator?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, calculator

I have an exercise that consists of using functional programming using javascript, the exercise is to make a calculator, I already did the multiplication without using recursion or the `/` operator but I don't understand how to do the division, I have tried various solutions but it doesn't work.

My operations

```
const adition = (a, b) => a + b;

const sustraction = (a, b) => a - b;

const multiplication = (a, b) => {
    return [...Array(b)].reduce((acc) => adition(acc, a), 0);
};
```

Comment: keep in mind that division is the inverse of multiplication (just as subtraction is the inverse of addition).

Comment: can you use a loop?

Comment: I can´t use loop (for, while, etc...), but i can use the other function, adition, sustraction, multiplication

Comment: @DavidAngarita - note that the words for the first two operations are _addition_ and _subtraction_..

Comment: this is your homework, so i hope your looking for hints not the answer. You should post all the things you tried and specific questions you have so we can give you feedback.

Comment: The questioner hasn't shown what they have tried or that any significant effort was made at all... and this is essentially their homework!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember how you did long division in grade school?

Implement that!

But if you can't remember:

- [Long Division | math is fun](https://www.mathsisfun.com/long_division.html)
- [How to do Long Division in 6 Steps (With Pictures)](https://www.prodigygame.com/main-en/blog/how-to-do-long-division/)
- [Step by Step Guide for Long Division](https://www.k5learning.com/blog/step-step-guide-long-division)
- [Intro to long division (remainders) (video) | Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/arithmetic-home/multiply-divide/mult-digit-div-2/v/division-2)